# Retrieve my friend's friends list using Java Restfb

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I am working on Restfb in Java and could manage to retrieve my friends list on my facebook. My question is: How can I retrieve, for instance, my friend's friends list? Is there any possibility to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t get the friendlist of your friends, that would be a major privacy issue.

Other threads:

- [facebook graph api..get friends of friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691402/facebook-graph-api-get-friends-of-friends/9443918#9443918)
- [Get a list of my friend's friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897749/get-a-list-of-my-friends-friends)